# What is correct way of creating threaded zeromq socket?

Tags: python, thread-safety, pyzmq

I'm wondering how to correctly create background thread that would be listenning some random port and pushing received object to Queue?

I want my socket wrapper to launch new thread, select some random port and start listenning on in. I have to be able to get this port number from socket wrapper.

I've come up with simple class:

```
class SocketWrapper(Thread):

    def __init__(self, socket_type, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Thread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._ctx = zmq.Context()
        self._socket = self._ctx._socket(socket_type)
        self.port = self._socket.bind_to_random_port('tcp://*')

        self._queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_requested:
            try:
                item = socket.recv_pyobj(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
                self._queue.put(item)
            except ZMQError:
                time.sleep(0.01)  # Wait a little for next item to arrive
```

However, zmq sockets can't be shared between threads, they are not thread-safe (http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq). So socket creation and binding should be moved to `run()` method:

```
class SocketWrapper2(Thread):

    def __init__(self, socket_type, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Thread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._socket_type = socket_type
        self._ctx = zmq.Context()

        self._queue = Queue()
        self._event = Event()

    def run(self):
        socket = self._ctx._socket(self._socket_type)
        self.port = self._socket.bind_to_random_port('tcp://*')
        self._event.set()

        while not self.stop_requested:
            try:
                item = socket.recv_pyobj(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
                self._queue.put(item)
            except ZMQError:
                time.sleep(0.01)  # Wait a little for next item to arrive

    def get_port(self):
        self._event.wait()
        return self.port
```

I had to add event to be sure that port is already binded before I can read it but it introduces risk of deadlock, when SocketWrapper2.get_port() is called before start(). This can be avoided by using Thread's _started Event:

```
    def get_port(self):
        if not self._started.is_set():
            raise RuntimeError("You can't call run_port before thread start.")
        self._event.wait()
        return self.port
```

Is this is at last thread-safe? Is there anything else to take care of?

Problem I still see here is that I want to get port right after SocketWrapper is created. Can I safely call Thread's `start()` in `__init__`?

Comment: `zmq.Context()` should be called in the thread. Move it to the `run` method. And you don't have code to deal with errors in the thread. If something happens before `self._event.set()`, you still deadlock. And if something happens later... what do you want to happen?

Comment: @tdelaney According to http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/morethanbindings.html#thread-safety zmq.Context is thread-safe. But you are right. Any Exception before `self._event.set()` would deadlock forever MainThread.

Comment: Oops... my zmq memory isn't as good as I thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying this solution a little to avoid deadlocking main thread:

```
def get_port(self):
    if not self._started.is_set():
        raise RuntimeError("You can't call run_port before thread start.")
    if not self._event.wait(1):
        raise RuntimeError("Couldn't get port after a while.")
    return self.port
```

This is not perfect. Since we delay get_port but it's simple and do the job. Any suggestions how to improve it?

Comment: Since there is no better answer I accept my answer.